# What does "account" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Machiavelli saw himself as a realist, someone who recognized that
>   people are fundamentally selfish. Thomas Hobbes shared that view: it
>   underpins his whole account of how he thought society ought to be
>   structured.

A little history of philosophy - Nigel Warburton, Chapter IX

What does "account" mean?

Comment: If you google **account meaning** you will find clear explanations of the use of the word in this context.

Answer (score 1):

One of the several meanings of "account" is a story, recollection, memoir, description of events. That is the meaning that applies in this case.